# Automating Firefox authentication window when system is locked using AutoIt

Tags: firefox, autoit

I am facing an issue in automating Authentication pop up in firefox when the system is locked.

I used following code

```
While 1=1
AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode","2")
WinWait("Authentication Required")
$title = WinGetTitle("Authentication Required") ; retrives whole window title  
$UN=WinGetText($title,"User Name:")  
ControlSend($title,"",$UN,"user");Sets Username  
$PWD=WinGetText($title,"Password:")  
Send("{TAB 1}")  
ControlSend($title,"",$PWD,"pass");Sets PWD  
Send("{ENTER}")
WEnd
```

Above code works fine whensystem is unlocked. But i am facing issue when the system got locked, what i observed is it is sending user name in the username text field but it is not able to perform "send{TAB 1}" when the system is locked. any help?

Comment: Well change while 1 = 1 to just while 1, because 1 will always equal 1 so there's no point in that statement. Try using just `Send("{TAB}")`

Comment: Hi JonBecher, Thanks for the reply. I tried using Send("{TAB}"), but still no luck. It keeps on entering user name and password in the username field when the system is locked. TAB will work only when i click on the pop up.

Comment: Try adding a `sleep(500)` before you send the tab command.

Comment: I gave a delay before sending TAB. Still script is entering user name and password in a username text field. Send("{TAB}") will work when the system is locked?

Comment: Have you tried using FF.au3 or IE.au3 instead of sending raw keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using Send() as much as you can.
Instead, use

```
ControlSend ( "title", "text", controlID, "string" [, flag] )
```

In your case its

```
ControlSend ( $title, "", "", "{ENTER}" )
```